# How do I use a Sony thermal printer (UP-D898DC)?

Tags: printing, sony

I am trying to install and use a Sony thermal printer on Ubuntu 20.04, specifically the [UP-D898DC](https://pro.sony/en_SE/products/medical-printers/up-d898dc).

Unfortunately Sony does not support this printer on Linux so there is no driver for Linux.

Do you have any idea how to install this printer on Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried just connecting it?

Comment: Does CUPS see it? `http://localhost:631` click "Administration",  then "Add Printer".

Comment: thanks so much. I use CUPS and it works.